# Oracle - how to calculate sum of highest salary for each dept

Tags: sql, oracle

As far as i could get, getting the MAX sal of each dept:

```
select ename, sal, deptno
from emp out
where sal = (
  select max(sal) from emp inside
  where out.deptno=inside.deptno
);
```

This returns 4 results, now I want the SUM of those 4 results, how do i do that? This seems not to work:

```
select ename, sum(sal), deptno
from emp out
group by deptno, sal, ename
having sum(sal) = (
  select max(sal) from emp inside
  where out.deptno=inside.deptno
);
```

it is returning the same result as first query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select sum(max_sal) as total_sum
from 
(
  select deptno, max(sal) as max_sal
  from emp
  group by deptno
) x
```

To get the highest salary for every department you can simply group by the department and use `max()` to get the highest. Use this as a subquery to sum these up.

Comment: Maybe add some explanation to you answer.